# java.util.calendar behaving strange

Tags: java, date, calendar, java.util.calendar

So, i found the java.util.Calendar, and tried to use it for a android project i'm working on.

I do not understand at all how Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK can return 7, when it's Thursday?
And now when it's August Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR returns 4, which doesn't make any sense at all!

I have tried GregorianCalendar too, and it gives exactly the same results.

Tried to find any documentation about how they count, but i can't find anything.
Seems like there is something very obvious, but which i just cannot find out what it is!

The code i wrote is here:

```
    // Get if daily or weekly
    boolean daily;
    daily = getPrefs.getBoolean("checkbox_daily", false);
    String day = "0";
    if (daily){
        switch(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK){
            case GregorianCalendar.MONDAY:
                Do_stuff();
                break;
            case GregorianCalendar.TUESDAY:
                Do_stuff();
                break;
            case GregorianCalendar.WEDNESDAY:
                Do_stuff();
                break;
            case GregorianCalendar.THURSDAY:
                Do_stuff();
                break;
            case GregorianCalendar.FRIDAY:
                Do_stuff();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` is constant,

you need `calendarInstance.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);`

Answer (score 1):

From [java.util.Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) docs:

> Calendar defines a locale-specific seven day week using two
>   parameters: the first day of the week and the minimal days in first
>   week (from 1 to 7). These numbers are taken from the locale resource
>   data when a Calendar is constructed. They may also be specified
>   explicitly through the methods for setting their values.
>
> When setting or getting the WEEK_OF_MONTH or WEEK_OF_YEAR fields,
>   Calendar must determine the first week of the month or year as a
>   reference point. The first week of a month or year is defined as the
>   earliest seven day period beginning on getFirstDayOfWeek() and
>   containing at least getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() days of that month or
>   year. Weeks numbered ..., -1, 0 precede the first week; weeks numbered
>   2, 3,... follow it. Note that the normalized numbering returned by
>   get() may be different. For example, a specific Calendar subclass may
>   designate the week before week 1 of a year as week n of the previous
>   year.